Simple circuit to compare the phase of 2 identical RF signals (no demod) tuned to the FM band?
For obvious reasons, the enormous array of radio components for the commercial bands all presume demodulation of the radio frequency for audio.  But, for a physics experiment testing the special theory of relativity, I need the raw radio frequency signal so I can compare their phases.  For reasons of economics and replicability by others, the circuit must tune to match any FM tower that the experimenter can drive to on a day trip (getting within a kilometer of the tower).
At present I am using a Hantek6254BD 4-CH 250 MHz oscilloscope in X-Y mode to examine the phase angle, but I need the signal amplified (which tuners do) and the frequency selected (which tuners do).  However, tuners demodulate into audible frequencies where the relative phase shift is too small to detect compared to that I am looking for in the 80 MHz - 108 MHz range.

Have you considered using a commercial mixer chip that generates a DC offset proportional to the phase of its input signals?

Have you considered a simpler experiment? 100 MHz clock + two antennae (Tx + Rx)  + amplifier and a phase detector (using any suitable mixer?  Then change the gap between the antenna.  But what effect do you need to understand in your experiment?

"However, tuners demodulate into audible frequencies where the relative phase shift is too small to detect compared to that I am looking for in the 80 MHz - 108 MHz range." - The relative phase shift of two identical RF sources will be the same after they are converted down to a low intermediate frequency (IF) by two mixers using the same local oscillator (LO). The advantage of doing that is the increased resolution of the phase measurement when done with a high sampling rate scope at a low IF instead of directly at the original RF frequency.

@glen_geek, that should have been 6254BD 4-CH  and thanks for pointing that out.

@yousif-alniemi yes I was looking at buying an MPD-1+ to eliminate the need for the oscilloscope, but since I needed a high sample rate oscilloscope anyway,  I figured that the MPD-1+ would be icing on the cake once I had clean signals.
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/1030/MPD_1_2b-3421428.pdf

@d-a-s I bought a 500mW FM transmitter, in part, for that purpose.  If the resonant circuit could be done with fixed reception frequency without using a trim capacitor, it would simplify the experiment since the tuning capacitor would be fixed in the Rx, and the Tx would be adjustable to match.  Then all that would be needed is a low noise amplifier on the output of the tuning capacitor and whatever impedance matching was needed for the oscilloscope.  However, the experiment needs a Line Of Sight range of about  500m and a commercial 100kW Tx seemed better.

@Raonoke I'm looking to see if there's a 180degree phase shift at about 500m distance based on this experiment https://www.techrxiv.org/users/681556/articles/679546-experimental-detection-of-superluminal-far-field-radio-waves-with-transverse-plasma-antennas , but one that doesn't require an expensive scope and sophisticated signal processing.  People aren't going to believe this experiment's results if it conflicts with the standard interpretation of Special Relativity so the instrument needs to be simple and cheap.
